# Is there a browser that can load a page > 4GB

Tags: web-browser

I'm encountering an issue with a web page that has to load a large table of data to my browser. When I try to load the page it crashes at 4GB (the data transfered by the server is much less than 4GB, it's just the rendering of the page that is taking up too much data). I have tried Firefox 55, Chrome 60 and Edge 40, using Windows 10 64bit.

I'm trying to load a large table of sales data from a [odoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odoo) server (rows should be products and columns orders). It's large because I'm trying to get a months sales out at once and don't want to do it one session at a time.

Comment: @KyleCooke Yours is a job for a [database](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) rather than a web browser. A database such as [FileMaker](http://www.filemaker.com/), [4D](http://www.4D.com/), H2, or Postgres is optimized to manage more data than can fit into RAM.

Comment: OK, this sounds like a hint for impovement for odoo. They should be able to display large datasets in the browser out of the box. But probably there is some export feature to Excel, CSV or something alike, for offline use?

Comment: Did you try with a 64 bit browser?